# Helm: How to refer a list of objects in manifest files

Tags: kubernetes-helm

**Values file**

```yaml
deploymentStrategy:
  istioTrafficRoute: false
  canary:
    steps: 
      - setCanaryScale:
          weight: 10    
      - setWeight: 90   
      - pause:
          duration: "60m" 
      - setWeight: 50
      - pause:
          duration: "10m"
```

**Deployment manifest**

How to refer to the complete steps object in a manifest

```yaml
{{- range $i, $steps := .Values.deploymentStrategy.canary.steps }}
        {{- range $key, $value := $steps }}
          - {{ $key }}: {{ $value | toYaml }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- end }}
```

Comment: `steps: 
      {{- range $i, $steps := .Values.deploymentStrategy.canary.steps }}
      {{- range $key, $value := $steps }}
      {{- if kindIs "map" $value }}
        - {{ $key }}:
            {{ . | toYaml }}
      {{- else }}
        - {{ $key }}: {{ . }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- end }}`

Comment: If you found the solution, please be so kind and add it as answer! That makes it easier for others who have the same question!